# Java Jease CMS, Index page setup

Tags: java, content-management-system

I have converted my static website into Jease, through localhost:8080/cms, and I can access my website using the URL localhost:8080/index.html and from there I can browse around my entire website. What I am not sure about, how can I configure Jease to directly go to index.html page as soon as I type localhost:8080? Because once I make it globally available I want to make sure the index.html page is accessed through mywebsite.com URL.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using JeaseCMS 2.8 and the default page already is index.html according to web.xml file.
But this welcome file isn't necessary.